# Integers in combo box won't databind

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have a combo box with a list of font sizes that I am trying to bind to an MVVM view model. The SelectedItem property is bound to my Viwe model property, FontSize. The drop-down list is fixed, so I declare the combo box items in the XAML for the combo box, like this:

```
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FontSize, Mode=TwoWay, 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              Width="60" Margin="2,0,3,0">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="10" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="12" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="18" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="24" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="36" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="48" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="60" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="72" />
</ComboBox>
```

Here is my problem: When I run the app, the combo items load fine. But when I select an item from the list, I get this error in the Output window:

```
Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem.
```

The other data bindings in the window are working fine. The full error message is reprinted below.

What is the error message telling me, and how do I fix this? Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Full error message:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: 12' from type 'ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.Int32' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem.
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: 12' (type 'ComboBoxItem'). BindingExpression:Path=FontSize; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=14640006); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem.
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ComboBox contains ComboBoxItems and you bound the selectedItem to an integer property which is causing the errors. When you select a ComboBoxItem it tries to set the ComboBoxItem as the SelectedItem but throws an error when trying to cast it as an integer. I would bind a collection of integers in your view model to the ComboBox.ItemsSource to fix this. This option  gives you the flexibility of reading the list from a database or a file.

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FontSize, Mode=TwoWay, 
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          Width="60" Margin="2,0,3,0" ItemsSource="{Binding FontSizeList}"/>
```

Comment: There are more than two ways to fix this, making statements like this is hardly ever a good idea.

Answer (score 10):

1. Set the `SelectedValuePath` to `Content`, this will make the `SelectedValue` the `Content` of the selected `ComboBoxItem`.
2. Bind the `SelectedValue` to your VM's property instead of the `SelectedItem`.

```
<ComboBox
    Width="60"
    Margin="2,0,3,0"
    SelectedValuePath="Content"
    SelectedValue="{Binding FontSize}">
```

(*Setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` and the `Mode` is not needed as they are set that way by default*)

Comment: I've seen you post answers to many questions. What do you do for a living that gives you the time to answer all those questions?

Comment: @evanb: Haha, i'm a university student (studying computer science & media), who currently has a semester break. Admittedly i spend a lot of time on SO even during the semester, probably too much actually. Edit: Aww, my answers are no longer "insightful"?

Comment: It's funny, I've tried to answer a few questions and see that you've posted answers to many of them within a few minutes of the questions being posted. You are definitely a very knowledgeable person and a great addition to the SO community. I was reading the comment you wrote on my answer and thought that some might think your answers are not insightful so I followed your advice, haha.

Comment: @KushalR: Not really. I also greatly prefer binding to data and using data templating where applicable. This solution is not something i would usually use, i rarely ever instantiate item containers like `ComboBoxItem` myself.